# How to query Azure table storage using rest API

Tags: python, rest, azure, http-get, azure-table-storage

i want to access my table in azure storage account.

```
import requests

import hashlib

import base64

import hmac

import datetime
storageAccountName = 'rishistorage1234' # your storage account name
storageKey='my-account-key'# your storage account access key
url = 'https://' + storageAccountName + '.table.core.windows.net/table1'
version = '2016-05-31' # x-ms-version
date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")  #x-ms-date
parameters = 'table1'
CanonicalizedResources = '/' + storageAccountName + '/' + parameters
CanonicalizedHeaders = 'x-ms-date:' + date 
stringToSign = 'GET\n\n\n\n\n' + CanonicalizedHeaders + '\n' + CanonicalizedResources
# note the b64decode of the storageKey
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(storageKey), 
msg=stringToSign, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
headers = {'x-ms-date': date,
     'x-ms-version': version,
       'Authorization': 'SharedKeyLite ' + storageAccountName + ':' + 
signature}

# send the request
#print signature
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print response
print response.headers
print response.content
```

sorry i was not able to copy everything as "code" and pls ignore the indentation error.
the name of the table is table1
the name of storage account is rishistorage1234
Acces key 1 is `my-account-key`.

the response i get is

```
    <Response [403]>
{'Content-Length': '419', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'x-ms-request-id,Content-Length,Date,Transfer-Encoding', 'x-ms-request-id': 'e3b01b8c-0002-0024-0d3d-b71dc2000000', 'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0', 'Date': 'Mon, 17 Apr 2017 05:40:23 GMT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>AuthenticationFailed</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en-US">Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:e3b01b8c-0002-0024-0d3d-b71dc2000000
Time:2017-04-17T05:40:24.3250398Z</m:message></m:error>
```

Comment: Please change your account key ASAP and never share your account key on a forum like this. Anyone who has access to your account key has full control over your storage account. Also, please tell us what is the error you're getting.

Comment: You will need to change your existing storage account key since it is still available in the edit history.

Comment: thank you for the alerting but this is a  trial account and no confidential data is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error information & code, I'm sure the issue was caused by using the incorrect `StringToSign` format in `SharedKeyLite` for for Azure Table service, that your `StringToSign` format is for Blob, not for Table, as below.

Your error code & information is belong to `AuthenticationFailed`, please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/common-rest-api-error-codes).

[image]

And the correct `StringToSign` format for Azure Table service should be as below, like `StringToSign = Date + "\n"+ CanonicalizedResource`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

if any one is looking for working python code for querying table from azure table storage using REST API, here's the code

```
import requests

import hashlib

import base64

import hmac

import datetime
storageAccountName = 'my-account-name' # your storage account name
storageKey='my-account-key'# your storage account access key
url = 'https://' + storageAccountName + '.table.core.windows.net/table-name'
version = '2016-05-31' # x-ms-version
date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")  #x-ms-date
parameters = 'table-name'
CanonicalizedResources = '/' + storageAccountName + '/' + parameters
CanonicalizedHeaders = 'x-ms-date:' + date 
stringToSign = date + '\n' + CanonicalizedResources
# note the b64decode of the storageKey
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(storageKey), 
msg=stringToSign, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
headers = {'x-ms-date': date,
       'x-ms-version': version,
       'Authorization': 'SharedKeyLite ' + storageAccountName + ':' + 
        signature,
       'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata '}

# send the request
#print signature
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print response
print response.headers
print response.content
```

For more operation refer this 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/table-service-rest-api

Comment: Not looking for python code, but the logic helped a lot! Thanks!

Comment: I just tried. This is not working. Raised Error: TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: you can encode the stringToSign, and then decode the signature, like this: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/TypeError%3A+Unicode-objects+must+be+encoded+before+hashing